# How to set complex config values for objects created in visual editor

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I'm using Sencha Architect.

I can't find a way to specify config value precisely enough in config editor.

Couple of examples:

1) I have Panel, and I want to set it's layout like that:

```
layout: {
    type: 'vbox'
    align : 'stretch',
    pack  : 'start',
}
```

But using config editor I cannot proceed further than setting it's type 'vbox'. How to set it's `align` and `pack` properties?

2) Combobox allows using simple array as store initializer. And it looks pretty convenient - for example if values are fixed, we could just write `... store: ['constant', 'massive']...`
But again, if I use config editor, I can set as `store` only preliminarily created object of type `Store`.

The question is, is there any way to get more freedom in setting config values without losing convenience of vusial editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. align and pack are direct property of panel. Select the panel and you can find them on search box at right inspector.
2. unfortunately you cant set a object in every property of sencha, some properties has a button where you can set a type: string, object, number.

Comment: Setting config type to object really solves problem in most cases.